# Protractor webdriver-manager permissions?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm on Windows Server 2016. Under my regular user account (which I added to the local Admin group) I cannot run protractor tests. I get `E/launcher - WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.` When I start ONLY webdriver-manager with another admin user account (Run cmd as different user and start webdriver-manager) and then run `protractor conf.js` as my regular user account the tests run fine. I'm beginning to think there is some permissions issue. Does running protractor and webdriver-manager require any extra permissions other than adding a user to the local Admin group? I've already restarted the computer and it's strange it is just the webdriver-manager as the problem.

Comment: This might also require java to run as the admin. To start the server, it calls a java command to run the selenium server jar file.

Comment: @cnishina Do you know which java command is called? I can test the command to see if it will run as myself

Comment: It probably is something like `java -jar path/to/selenium-standalone.jar`. The path is the downloaded path. So this path might be in `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/`